# Неполное понимание построения таблицы префиксов в методе Кнута-Морисса-Пратта

Tags: python, алгоритм

Ниже одна из классических реализации построения списка префиксов. В этой реализации понятны почти все пункты, за исключением того момента когда мы в случае неравенства букв в позициях `m` и `i` и неравенства переменной `m` нулю, назначаем ей значение из массива по индексу на единицу меньшую: `m = aux[m-1]`. Почему просто его не обнулить? Так же, что означает i=0, почему с 1, а не с 0?

```
def lsp_table_creator(W):
    aux = [0] * len(W)
    i = 1
    m = 0
    while i < len(W):
        if W[i] == W[m]:
            m += 1
            aux[i] = m
            i += 1
        elif W[i] != W[m] and m != 0:
            m = aux[m-1]
        else:
            aux[i] = 0
            i += 1
    return aux
```

Answer (score 2):

Что такое **m**? Это длина рассматриваемого префикса.

На каждом шаге, удлиняя суффикс, мы может получить совпадающий с ним префикс только на единицу большей длины, чем предыдущий. А может эта длина и уменьшиться, и иногда действительно до нуля. Вот только если уменьшить сразу до нуля и потом проверять по порядку все длины по нарастанию, то придётся проверять много символов. В целях оптимизации длину **m** уменьшают по одному, чтобы максимально переиспользовать уже имеющуюся информацию - тогда приходится использовать **только одну проверку на каждое уменьшение**.

Без этой оптимизации время работы станет квадратичным, а с её применением - линейным - за счёт того, что **общее количество уменьшений длины префикса не превышает длины строки**

> Так же, что означает i=0, почему с 1, а не с 0?

Достаточно сюда поглядеть:

```
if W[i] == W[m]:
```